# How to extact data from a JSON data with CURL

Tags: r, curl

I have a curl request that authenticates with the username and password.

```
library(curl)
library(rjson)
library(jsonlite)

link1<-paste0("The URL of the required data source")
resp<- curl_fetch_memory(link1,h)
zips<- jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content,multiple = FALSE))
```

The expected result is that of a list within a list , but i am getting a list with a row of characters all merged ...
Am i moving on with the wrong logic here? Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: any reproducible example you can provide?

Comment: Either the bug is (a) in the connection to the URL, (b) in the way you are fetching the data, or (c) in the conversion. Do you have any idea where? That is, you show 3 lines of code---which is the first one that produces an unexpected result? We can't really help without anything to test on...